# Theme files gone after extension installed

Tags: magento2, extensions, static-content-deploy

I am really not familiar with Magento 2 - a colleague has built one mainly using a **pre-purchased theme** but I haven't been involved until today.

This morning I manually installed an **extension** which seemed to be just a matter of **uploading a folder** and its contents into the `public_html/app folder`.

Then used **PuTTY** to **enable, update, compile, clean the cache**. The dashboard seems fine and the **extension** was installed fine.

However on the front end, a whole pile of files in `public_html/pub/static` have disappeared and the site is broken. Any idea how this could have happened? Was it during the update/compile? I believe we have a backup but just wondering for future reference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After compile you need to deploy static files again. Use command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Thanks - I just found this out after I posted . Have run that and need to run it again with en_GB after it as all I got was a load of en_US stuff, but on the right track now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command from command line :

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: You mean that he should roll his face over keyboard?

Comment: after compilation, you need to generate file again, so it is better to run those command from command line.

Comment: Do you mind to elaborate the connection between changing theme and setup:upgrade, indexer:reindex command plus why he should run both cache:clean and cache:flush?

Comment: That command just to clear cache, because magento many time create issue dua to that.

Comment: How does it answer my question? I mean, your answer looks little bit like "hey dude, i do not really know what i am doing but try to run all commands and cross your fingers". But I might miss some connections between processes that is why I am asking for details.

Comment: @hawthorn Now you issue have been solve, right?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - yes, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
php bin/magento module:enable EXTENSION_NAME
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clear  clean
```

That is what I had ^^. Just ran

```
php bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy en_GB
```

and am back in business. Thanks for the help.